# Why does my Gibbs sampler find two optimals?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, gibbs, bayesian-optimization

[EDITED] I am using a Gibbs Sampler to find a Bayesian optimization to my multilevel (hierarchical) model (2 levels). However, when I run multiple chains (each chain having different starting values) my Gibbs sampler seems to convergence to two different values. Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to solve it?

The trace plot below shows my problem. Here I considered four different chains and used 100,000 iterations. The picture are the last 400 iterations of one of the coefficients that I am trying to estimate.
[image]

Some extra info about my model: The first stage contains about 47 variables (half of them are dummies for seasonality and the others are (continuous) marketing variables like the cost of a marketing media or a continuous control variable, as I am trying to estimate the effect marketing has on sales) and my second stage model contains only dummies (about 10) and estimates one of the coefficients of the first stage. That is, I am trying to estimate the coefficients of the following model:
(first stage) 
\begin{equation} y_t = alpha + beta_{1,t}X_{1t} + beta_2 X_{2t} + beta_3 X_{3t} + ... + \epsilon_t \end{equation} 
(second stage) 
\begin{equation} beta_{1,t} = phi_1 z_{1t} + phi_2 z_{2t} + ... + \upsilon_t. \end{equation}
I have set all the priors to uninformative as I wanted to check whether the results somewhat correspond with a MLE approach.

**EDIT:**

My initial thoughts where:

(1) Could it be because of 'bad' starting points. However, you would then expect that the four chains would convergence to the same point when letting the Gibbs sampler run with 1,000,000 iterations and that is not happening unfortunately.

(2) Could it be because the some chain(s) get 'stuck' in a local optima?

(3) Is there maybe an endogeneity problem?

Comment: What do you mean by finding "two optimals"? Gibbs sampler samples values from the distribution, it doesn't do optimization. You mean bimodal distributions? If yes, this suggests problems with convergence, but hard to say without knowing further details about your data and the model.

Comment: Not the best choice of works, I agree. What I mean is that if I run my model lets say 4 times and check the trace plots of all parameters/coefficients. It seems like my gibbs sampler finds two values to converge too for a couple of these parameters.

Comment: So you have problems with convergence. It is hard to say more without knowing more about your data and the model.

Comment: The question needs further details like the model itself. Please provide them in the question, not in the comments. You can also include graphs of (non-)convergence of the Gibbs chains.

Comment: What happens if you use 10x more iterations? 400 is a very small number.

Comment: @Tim The picture only displays the last 400 iterations of the total 100000 iterations. I just ran the exact same code for 1000000 iterations and is still looks the same unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like the lower chains are mixing and have converged to a common solution. The upper chain looks like it has a much larger within-chain variance in comparison to the lower ones and has potentially not converged. You should keep running the chains and see how the upper chain evolves.

You could also increase the number of chains to see what happens if more then one chain gets a starting point close to the upper one (maybe one of them did in the initial samples?)

> PS. if you write \begin{equation} and then \end{equation } around your equation it looks more clear

Comment: I also thought that it might have been because of 'bad' starting points. However, you would then expects that the four chains would convergence to the same point when letting the Gibbs sampler run with 1,000,000 iterations and that is not happening unfortunately. The other two things that crossed my mind where, (1) could it be because the some chain(s) get 'stuck' in a local optima? Or (3) is there maybe an endogeneity problem?